# C# как получить данные из объекта <T> типа

Tags: c#, .net

Есть класс

```
public class Table<T> : ITable<T>, IDisposable where T: class
```

В нем метод, который принимает объект типа <T>

```
public string Insert(T obj)
```

Как получить данные из полей этого объекта. Пробовал так

```
obj.GetType().GetField(field).GetValue(something)
```

, но не понял какой объект нужно записывать вместо "something"

Comment: раз уж начали использовать интерфейсное программирование, то просто напишите where T: class, IEntity. в IEntity добавьте необходимые свойства и реализуйте их. использование Reflection должно быть в каком-то универсальном случае, а у вас обычный метод, который почему-то решили делать обобщенным. я бы вобще отказался от обобщения в данном случае, а передал бы в Insert с параметром интерфейса или класса. не люблю абстрактное программирование, ни к чему хорошему оно не приводит.

Comment: @АлексейОбухов, если уж начинать идти в конкретику, то и нужды в этом классе не будет)

Comment: передавать нужно объект из которого ты хочешь получить значение. Если хочешь получить значения из `obj` - передавай `obj`

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, помогло. Можно это как ответ оформить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод [`.GetValue`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue?view=net-6.0) в качестве параметра принимает объект из которого ты хочешь получить значение, либо `null`, если поле статическое.

В данном случае, если нужно получить значение из `obj` его и надо передавать:

```
obj.GetType().GetField(field).GetValue(obj)
```